# CORS fails on cached GET only

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, cors

I have a web application that makes a cross domain GET request.  This fails but still returns a 200 response.  I opened Chromes debugger and it never fails...I then uncheck the "Disable cache" settings under Network and I am able to get it to happen.  This seems to only happen when I navigate away from my app, then back to it.  For example:

Caching Enabled:

1. Open my web app (everything is good)
2. Navigate to google.com
3. Hit the back button to navigate back to my web app
4. Initial GET request fails (no OPTIONS request is sent) and is shown coming from my page.htm
5. All subsequent CORS (including GET) pass with flying colors.

Caching Disabled:

1. Open my web app (everything is good)
2. Navigate to google.com
3. Hit the back button to navigate back to my web app
4. Initial GET is successful (Options is sent), no errors and is shown coming from my script.js

My search skills must be lacking, because I cant seem to find the reason for this behavior

Comment: sounds like some kind of bug.

Comment: Try open it on a new browser, or use incognito mode. It may be cached on your browser for a while.

Comment: @DatTran Ive restarted the browser wiped all the cache, and I can reproduce easily.  Ive tried everything.